# Updating state with fetch then using state in useEffect doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have a component in React where in `useEffect` I make two API calls and set two states. After still in `useEffect` I am trying to set another state with one of the states updated by the API. If I do this by keeping the square brackets parameter of `useEffect` empty it won't set the state. If I pass the state constants in the brackets it goes into an infinite loop.

```
async function fetchData() {
    const agentRes = await fetch("http://localhost:3004/agentsdata");
        agentRes
            .json()
            .then(res => setAgents(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

    const queueRes = await fetch("http://localhost:3004/queuedata");
        queueRes
            .json()
            .then(res => setBaseQueues(res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

useEffect(() => {

    fetchData();

    let pge;

    if (props.location.data !== undefined) {
        pge = props.location.data.page;
    }
    else {pge = 1;}

    setUser(props.match.params.user);
    setPage(pge);


    let lowerB = (0 +((pge - 1) * 10));
    let upperB = 10 + ((pge - 1) * 10);

    setQueues(baseQueues.slice(lowerB, upperB)); // here the state is not getting set.
}, [queues])
```

How do I make it so I can set that state as well as I need to do it in `useEffect`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const doAsyncStuff = async () => {
     await fetchData(); // wait for this data to load
     const { data } = props.location;
     let pge = data !== undefined ? data.page : 1;
     setUser(props.match.params.user);
     setPage(pge);
     
     let lowerB = (0 +((pge - 1) * 10));
     let upperB = 10 + ((pge - 1) * 10);
     
     setQueues(state => state.slice(lowerB, upperB)); // change here
  }
  doAsyncStuff();
}, [queues])
```

First I think you need to wait for the data to load, so you have to await for `await fetchData();`

and then while setting `setQueues` you have to do `setQueues(state => state.slice(lowerB, upperB));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simpler chema:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, [queues])

useEffect(() => {
  let pge;

  if (props.location.data !== undefined) {
      pge = props.location.data.page;
  }
  else {pge = 1;}

  setUser(props.match.params.user);
  setPage(pge);

  let lowerB = (0 +((pge - 1) * 10));
  let upperB = 10 + ((pge - 1) * 10);

  setQueues(baseQueues.slice(lowerB, upperB)); // here baseQueues is updated.
}, [baseQueues])
```

... **but probably you don't need majority of this**

- `queues` are derived data;
- this subset can be 'calculated' on each render after page prop change;
- after feching page param can be out of range - redirect?;

Comment: This answer was partly correct, I removed queues from the second parameter in first useEffect and it works correctly.

Comment: all depends on usage context, entire component - empty array in `useEffects` makes this only once fired (like `componentDidMount`) - place here a prop/variable when refeching needed

Comment: Note that this implementation is problematic as it captures stale closures. Note that your effect is dependent on  the ```props.match.params.user``` and ```props.location.data.page``` thus they should be included in the dependency array. Any change in the ```props.location.data.page``` will not be handled by the effect leading to stale data in ```baseQueues``` 's state.

Comment: @chitova263 original was not `props.location.data.page` changes aware, too ... you can return both fetched data from original `fetchData()` ... we're working on fragments, w/o proper context

Comment: @xadm  ... we're working on fragments, w/o proper context . Yeah you're right

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to fix the code and given detailed explanation in the comments on how to use the useEffect hook the right way. I highly recommend you to read [this blog post](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abramov it will clear most of your misconceptions on your usage of the `useEffect` hook

```js
//since you data fetching code does not depend on anything inside your component you can hoist it outside the component.

async function getAgentData(){
  try{
     const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3004/agentsdata');
     return await response.json();
  } catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}

async function getQueueData{
  try{
     const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3004/queuedata');
     return await response.json();
  } catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}


function YourComponent(props){

   // destructure your props
   const { location: { data }, match } = props;
   const { params: { user } } = props.match;

   // Split your hooks by concern keep the related code together
   useEffect(() => {

      setUser(user);

   // add ALL you dependencies for this effect
   }, [user])

   // Second Effect
   useEffect(() => {

     const pge = (data == undefined)? 1 : data.page;
     const lowerB = (0 +((pge - 1) * 10));
     const upperB = 10 + ((pge - 1) * 10);

     setPage(pge);

     async function fetchData(){
       const agentRes = await getAgentData();
       setAgents(agentRes);

       const queueRes = await getQueueData();

       // Note: There need to first save it to state; then retrieve then slice then update again. When all you need is this
       setBaseQueues(queueRes.slice(lowerB, upperB));
     }

     //call the function here
     fetchData();

     //Add the ALL the dependencies of this effect i.e all props, functions, state variables inside 
     //YourComponent that you have used in this effect
     //In this case this effect is only run when this.props.location.data is changes, which is the desired behaviour
   }, [ data ])

   return <>Whatever</>
}
```